# when I apply median filter to image, it turns purple. why?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a image.I added salt & pepper noise to this image. After that I applied 2D median filter to remove noise from image. But after this process, the image converted purple.

[image]

And here is my codes.

```
M=3;
N=3;

modifyA=np.pad(image, [(math.floor(M/2),math.floor(N/2))])

B = np.zeros([(image.shape[0]),(image.shape[1])]) 
med_indx = round((M*N)/2); #MEDIAN INDEX


for i in range ((modifyA.shape[0])-(M-1)-1):          
  for j in range ((modifyA.shape[1])-(N-1)-1):                
    temp = modifyA[i:i+(M-1), j:j+(N-1)]           #
    #RED,GREEN AND BLUE CHANNELS ARE TRAVERSED SEPARATELY          
    for k in range (2):           
      tmp = temp[:,:,k]           
      B[i,j] = np.median(tmp[:])   


B = B.astype(np.uint8) 
imgplot = plt.imshow(B)
plt.show()
```

Where could the error be?

Comment: Because 2D scalar data is rendered as a pseudocolor image.

Comment: Do you have any ideas, how I can fix this in code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you want to process a color image, your output must be a 3D array, not a 2D array. `range(2)` is 2 values, not 3. In your koop over `k` you overwrite earlier results, only the last loop iteration matters.

Answer (score 0):

As [@gre_gor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794749/gre-gor) wrote in their comment, `imshow` is using a pseudocolor. More specifically, it is using the common colormap `viridis` by default if the image is not RGB(A).

Take a look at the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

To display a grayscale version of your image refer to this part of the doc:

> The input may either be actual RGB(A) data, or 2D scalar data, which will be rendered as a pseudocolor image. For displaying a grayscale image set up the colormapping using the parameters cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255.

Comment: my image is colorful. When I change code as imgplot = plt.imshow(B, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255 ). it turns black. It doesn't work